# Emulator not starting in Android Studio Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

The following error pops up when I start the emulator:

```
/root/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  54
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Comment: Try to switch your video card driver from _nouveau_ to your computer's graphic card (nvidia or whatever you have)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

It can be used for the Direct Lunching of the AVD...